# Develop map app based on Baidu SDK , android studio,permission error

Tags: android, permissions, maps

E/PermissionCheck: permission check result is: 601
Flash back when the app is running on the true phone

I am new to android studio , I don`t know how to resolve the error,please help me , thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.